# Formula for compound interest with N withdrawals

Tags: algebra-precalculus, finance

I have a calculator that allows users to see how much they need to save per period (month, year, etc) when putting money into a savings account. There are N withdrawals made in the end, with N ranging from 1 to 9, and years ranging from 1 to 22 (making periods range from 1 to 12*22=264). Each withdrawal is made in one period. For example:

```
Year      : 1  2  3  4  5  6  7
Withdrawal: 0  0  0  0  7  7  9
```

Users input how much what they're saving for costs now, how much the interest rate on that cost is, the rate their investment will grow, and for how many years they'll be saving. The calculator outputs how much they should save per period.

I am trying to allow for a lump-sum investment though. Setting the period to 1 in the calculator does not output a correct answer. Is there a formula that anyone knows off-hand for this?

To be clear: with the inputs described above, I am looking for the output of what the initial investment amount should

-------------EDIT------------

Example input:

```
years: 4
# of withdrawals: 2
goal (sum of withdrawals): $22,601
interest rate: 0.06 (6%)
```

I need it to output the following:

```
lump sum deposit: $19,454
```

Comment: Do you want to know what they should be investing now so that it's possible to make the specified withdrawals in the future?

Comment: Yes, basically. The withdrawals aren't specified--they are calculated based on other parameters not listed, but for the sake of the formula you can assume that.

Comment: Your example does not seem to have a single deposit at the start as your question describes.  One deposit of $6893$ can't give you $22601$ output in any reasonable number of year.  You say there are two withdrawals, but don't say when they come out.  Somehow it is encoded in 5 years and two withdrawals.

Comment: The example I gave was a working annual deposit example. The reason I posted it was so that I could reference it in the comment I made in your answer.

Comment: You asked about a single initial deposit, which is what I answered.  I don't know what this has to do with it, and your comment doesn't seem to refer to it.

Comment: @RossMillikan I apologize, I was still in the process of making edits. Does what I asked make more sense now?

Comment: No, you still show two withdrawals, year 4, and an annual deposit.  This does not match the 7,7,9 you started with and I solved.  7+7+9=23, not 22.601, and it doesn't take 19 to fund that.

Comment: @RossMillikan The second example that I added in the edit was a working input/output example of an annual deposit output, placed there to compare to the lump-sum-deposit that I made reference to after. I apologize for writing this so poorly, I'll go back and edit it.

Comment: @RossMillikan the initial 7, 7, 9 example was meant to illustrate the fact that there was not a consistent number of withdrawals (a formula for that can be easily found online). The example after the ---edit--- marker is an example input/output for the calculator.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/12635/discussion-between-ross-millikan-and-user3191820)

Comment: It appears you are trying to convince me that the calculator is working in this example, but have not defined it well enough to check.  That's OK, I don't care.  I showed the formula you asked for and that it works for your example.  You can check that it is correctly applying 6% interest per year and comes out with zero at the end.  If you can't get the calculator to do that, learn to use it or learn to use Excel (which I used for the example).

Comment: Thanks for the tip to use Excel--I've verified that your solution was correct, and that the calculator has been using a "trick" to get seemingly correct solutions. I didn't create the thing, so I was under the assumption that the person who did had done it correctly. I'm also not allowed to divulge some of the other details regarding the calculator due to company policy, hence why  I had difficulty explaining everything. Thanks for your patience though. I'd +1 your answer if I could :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just discount each of the desired withdrawals.  If the initial deposit is at the start of year 1, the withdrawals are at the ends of the years indicated, and the annual interest is $i$, to get that withdrawal of $7$ at year $5$ requires $\frac 7{(1+i)^5}$.  To get your whole stream, you must deposit $\frac 7{(1+i)^5}+\frac 7{(1+i)^6}+\frac 9{(1+i)^7}$ at the start.  Here is a table showing that $16.15105$ is sufficient 
$$\begin {array}\  Year&Flow, end of year&Balance, end of year\\0&16.15104502&16.15104502\\1&&17.12010772\\2&&18.14731418\\3&&19.23615303\\4&&20.39032221\\5&-7&14.61374155\\6&-7&8.490566038\\7&-9&0 \end {array}$$

Comment: I didn't get the output I needed using this. I'll post an example input/output from the calculator.

Comment: Using your formula, the output was an initial deposit of \$19,560, and the final balance I had was \$35. This is using the same inputs as I had in the example I just added.

Comment: At $i=0.06$, I get an initial deposit of $16.15105$ and it comes out even nicely with withdrawals of $7$ in year $5$, $7$ in year $6$ and $9$ in year $7$